# What's the "elevator pitch" for writers.SE?

Tags: discussion, big-7, stackexchange

Per the fourth question of the [7 essential meta beta questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/), this question can serve as the place to decide on the description for what this community will be about.

Since we're all existing/aspiring writers, should be a piece of cake, right? ;)

Refer to [Stack Exchange Naming For Dummies](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/stack-exchange-naming-for-dummies/) for the company line, some insight and generic suggestions.

**Edited to add more information for those answering**:

Instead, let's start with a killer "elevator pitch!" Joel will be blogging about the elevator pitch approach to naming, but to get you started:
The Elevator Pitch

This isn't as easy as it sounds. Imagine the user who will never read your FAQ and you have two seconds to grab their attention. It should be catchy but descriptive. It should be thoroughly clear but painfully concise. Make every... word... count.

Here are some creative examples:

- Gawker: Daily Manhattan media news and gossip. Reporting live from the center of the universe.
- Gizmodo: The gadget guide. So much in love with shiny new toys, it’s unnatural.
- Autoblog: We obsessively cover the auto industry.
- DumbLittleMan: So what do we do here? Well, it’s simple. 15 to 20 times per week we provide tips that will save you money, increase your productivity, or simply keep you sane.
- Needcoffee.com: We are the Internet equivalent of a triple espresso with whipped cream. Mmmm…whipped cream.

Use it as a Tagline

A shorter elevator pitch can be used as a tagline — something you can display in the header at the top of the page. If it doesn't fit, consider shortening it or creating a separate tagline. Here are some great examples:

- Slashdot: News for nerds. Stuff that matters.
- Lifehacker: Don’t live to geek, geek to live!
- The Simple Dollar: Financial talk for the rest of us.

The Motto (don't forget your logo)

A logo begs for it own little, short tagline — like a motto. Maybe the tagline inspires the logo; Maybe it's the other way around. Mottos make good t-shirt, bumper stickers, and other marketing material. Either way, you'll recognize a good motto when you see it:

- Just do it.
- Think Different.
- The Uncola.
- Intel inside.
- Like a rock.
- The king of beers.

…and perhaps all this leads to a proper name and domain for your site… eventually. So let's start from the basics. Come up with a killer elevator pitch, tagline, and/or motto!

Comment: Why the "meta" tag? Just wondering.

Comment: @neilfein: I'd think because it applies to the larger issue of the community, and doesn't directly contribute to the content of the site.  Meta as opposed to writers.  Yes/no?

Comment: @Zayne - This question is on the meta.writers site, so it's redundant to tag it "meta". It'd be like tagging a question on the regular site "writers".

Comment: @neilfein: Don't look at me - this is my first "meta" SE experience.  The tag was there, I used it.  If you feel it is inappropriate, remove it. :)

Comment: @Zayne - Okay, done. I asked because I thought it was possible the tag was there for a reason.

Comment: Small suggestion: replace "existing" with "established".

Answer (score 7):

Elevator Pitch:

- At Writers we answer your questions about the act of writing and business of publishing

Tagline:

- Writers: helping you put the impossible into words

Comment: +1 for the awesome tagline.  Not quite sold on that elevator pitch, but I haven't heard a better one yet.

Answer (score 3):

Elevator Pitch:

Braggy version:
You don‘t know how to write that postcard to your Mom? Well, ask your Mom. You don‘t know how to write a bestseller? Ask us!

Comment: You don‘t know how to write a bestseller? Don't ask us either, we don't know!  ;-)   Or, if you really mean it (remember: truth in advertising), John, I'll have to ask this question on the main site.  ;-)

Comment: @jae: Truth is overrated!

Answer (score 3):

Elevator pitch from [Randomman159](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/users/35/randomman159) given in [this question](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21/what-should-our-faq-contain/87#87) that really ought to be voted on here.

So what is {our future name}?

{our future name} is a place for authors, editors, reviewers, professional writers, and aspiring writers to ask and answer questions regarding writing.

Answer (score 1):

In all seriousness:

Based on what I've seen in the first few days of the site, it looks like people want to focus on writing **techniques and processes**. (This neatly avoids sites like the [foo] Language and Usage sites, which are language dependent.)

Focusing on the techniques of and the processes of writing, including ways to motivate a writer and keep them on-target, topics that are important to not only writers but to people who manage writers, such as editors and managers. We also can make it clear to experienced Stack Exchange users that properly-asked subjective questions are welcome here.

Comment: I tend to disagree.  If there's no elevator pitch, this beta shouldn't exist - otherwise what did we commit to?

Comment: @Zayne - I think my point about making this more specific as the site matures was distracting from the contend of the pitch; I removed it, as the point is self-evident in any case (of course we'd revise it as the site changes!).

Answer (score 1):

I almost feel guilty to put this here, it's so awful, but the elevator pitch *does* include a nickname, and I honestly can't resist:

I feel like the nickname should be a pun like (forgive me) Getting It Write.

Comment: That made me think of another terrible pun: "Write Aid" ... Probably only makes sense to people from the USA though ;)

Comment: Haha oh man I am so all for a lame pun.

Comment: Also why the downvote?

Comment: on meta, downvotes mean that people do not agree (as opposed to finding your suggestion not useful).  It's simply how we're going to sort the suggestions.  Upvote whichever you think would be a good elevator pitch, downvote the ones you don't like.  There's no rep change.

Comment: Ohh, I didn't realize. In that case I understand the downvote; I'd do the same if I saw a pun like that ;D

Answer (score -1):

Writers {querying | interrogating | interviewing | asking | questioning} other writers.
{Improve | Develop | Enhance | Refine | Transform | Hone} your craft.

Comment: Disagreed. Sounds more like an elevator pitch for English SE, but with the {s going on in there, it looks somewhat like what a programmer would code up.

Comment: JFW -- you caught me...I'm a coder.  Maybe it's one of those things that's only us geeks think is funny :P

Comment: ... -3 downvotes for you though? :( Do they have the same effect as they have outside of meta? (-3 reputation?)

Comment: @JFW - downvotes do not have a rep effect (flagging is the only thing that does).  Instead they simply say "I do not agree."  How else will we pick the best elevator pitch/tagline/motto?

Comment: The programmer in me wonders what syntax that is.  Res would be () instead of {}, which CSH would be , instead of |.  *headscratching*

Comment: @jae It's a construction most often used in documentation to indicate that you should select among the given choices when typing actual code/commands.  I thought using actual code would make all the liberal arts majors' heads explode. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Elevator Pitch:

Obvious one:
If you have a question about writing, we have the answer.

Comment: The reason I don't like this one is you can replace "writing" with any other stack exchange site topic.  It's not unique enough.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to down vote, but I also think this one sounds too generic.

Answer (score -2):

Writing questions and answers about writing.

Answer (score -2):

NothingToInstall. I understand the domain is available. :)

Comment: Even though you tried to make a joke about the domain, you made it in the wrong question -- besides, naming was deprecated when we failed to come up with a good name for [gaming](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/1/14)

Answer (score -2):

Elevator Pitch:

Mysterious:
If it can be scribbled on a piece of paper or punched into pixels on the screen, we know how to do it.