# What should our FAQ contain?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, big-7

I'll begin:

```
What kind of questions can I ask here?

{Our future name} is for writers and is about writing of any kind. If you have a question about …

    * writing as an art or as a labour and its niceties  

and it is not about …

    * specific languages and their grammar
    * linguistics

… then you're in the right place to ask your question!
```

(I cannot see the community wiki checkbox, so I'll flag it to moderators)

Answer (score 6):

I'd add for on-topic:

- General editing and copy-editing proceedures
- Submitting work for publication
- Finding an agent
- Working with illustrators and layout professionals ([meta question](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32/illustrations-and-layouts-for-books))
- Technical tools which aid in the writing process ([meta question](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31/how-technical-should-questions-on-writer-be))

For off-topic

- Technical details about a character's occupation, skills, or hobbies that might best be asked on a occupation, skill, or hobby-focused question and answer site ([meta question](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20/is-it-appropriate-to-ask-questions-on-specialist-knowledge-areas))
- The graphic design side of illustration or layouts ([meta question](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32/illustrations-and-layouts-for-books))
- Specific details of the usage of a computer program for writing ([meta question](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31/how-technical-should-questions-on-writer-be))
- "Critique my writing.  What do you think?  How can it be improved?" ([meta question](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58/should-we-encourage-users-to-give-samples-of-their-writing-for-critique))
- Questions about grammar and usage.  These are covered by [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) ([meta question](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/q/93/26).)

Feel free to tighten these up, combine them, and create a set of high quality lists from this start.

Comment: Do we want to add that we're not the place for specific questions of grammar and usage?  I assume we don't really want to cover this stuff, since there's already an English Language and Usage SE.

Comment: @sjohnston - answer's CW, so go ahead.  I think yes.

Comment: Please note that critique questions are now on-topic, so this is slightly out of date.

Answer (score 3):

So what is {our future name}?

{our future name} is a place for authors, editors, reviewers, professional writers, and aspiring writers to ask and answer questions regarding writing.

I dunno, just an idea :)

Comment: this sounds like a great elevator pitch.  Did you submit this on that question?

Comment: @justkt - Agreed.