# How does the content on this site differ from the English Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I can see how there could be some overlap in content on the two sites.

What does this site focus on, and what is disallowed and should be asked on the [English](http://english.stackexchange.com) site instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This site focuses on writing style and technique, questions about editing, publishing, finding an agent, etc.  Anything involved with the process of writing a book (or something else) to getting it accepted by a publisher is within our realm.

This site disallows grammar questions, and any language-specific question.  It disallows questions about the subject matter about which you're writing.  It disallows questions about getting illustrations.

We are not limited to creative writing; poetry, playwriting, and nonfiction are also within our realm of expertise.

Honestly, I don't see its similarities to English other than that it happens to be conducted in English.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.