# Will we get fancy site design like Math.SE and English.SE?

Tags: discussion, design

Writers.SE is the first Stack Exchange site I've been involved with, namely because it's one of the few subjects that I can actually help with. As such, I'm not really sure how the development of a SE site works outside of the "proposal-commitments-private/public beta" system. I look at the older SE sites like Math.SE and English.SE, and they have really cool looking sites. Do we get one of those at some point?

(I realize this is a really unimportant question at this point, but I'm quite curious.)

Comment: A relevant post (on this meta) by one of our Community Managers from last week: [Custom Writing design and logo - Information gathering](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2492/24064) :)

Comment: Update: [Your new site design is live!](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2566/24064)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, once we are done with beta and are a full site, we will get our own design.  Part of the reason it is so important to come up with a killer [elevator pitch](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/whats-the-elevator-pitch-for-writers-se) is that this helps to determine our design.

Also important is voting to get users up to the threshold where they can close questions and such outside of beta, because this is a major gate for getting out of beta.  So keep voting!

Comment: What is the threshold outside of the beta?

Comment: @Fox Cutter - 2000 to edit other people's questions and answers, 3000 to close, 10000 for deletion votes and access to moderator tools.

Comment: @Fox Cutter: See this blog post for "When will my site graduate?" http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/

Comment: It seems impossible for someone to accumulate 10,000 reputation...

Comment: @JFW - then imagine 200,000 (as accumulated by at least one SO member).  When we get bigger, it won't be as hard as you think.

Answer (score 0):

OK, subjective, but I really like the current design with the hand-drawn icons. I like the colors too.

Comment: It's a nicely crafted design, but it's shared among all the beta sites, and it doesn't really scream "writing".  Jin does a great job with all the designs - I'm confident whatever he comes up with for Writing will be as good or better.